# Only write some of the fields of a struct

Tags: c++, struct

Let's say I have a struct that looks like

```
struct REC { 
    char dont_print;
    int also_don't_print;
    long print_this;
    char also_print_this
};
```

If I were to write all of the fields, it would look like

```
out_file.write((char*) &rec, sizeof(struct REC));
```

What's the best way to only write the last fields? I thought of several options, but each of them seem unclear and could break if other parts of the code change.

1. `out_file.write((char*) &rec.print_this, sizeof(struct REC) - sizeof(char) - sizeof(int));`
2. `out_file.write((char*) &rec.print_this, sizeof(long) + sizeof(char));`
3. `out_file.write((char*) &rec + sizeof(char) + sizeof(int), sizeof(struct REC) - sizeof(char) - sizeof(int));`
4. `out_file.write((char*) &rec + sizeof(char) + sizeof(int), sizeof(long) + sizeof(char));`

I was wondering if there's some better way, especially something that references the field names rather than the types.
Note: In my case I'll be doing this for a few different structs, all of which have the same few fields that I would like to ignore, but have different fields that come after those.

Comment: Assuming you're using an `ostream`, can you not just do eg. `out_file << rec.print_this << rec.also_print_this`? See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) for the docs. If you're fixed with using binary output, you can use `out_file.write((char *)&rec.print_this)`.

Comment: That's definitely a possibility, although sometimes the structs have many fields.

Comment: So define a member function that takes an `ofstream` and writes the relevant fields to it - then you can avoid duplicating this sort of code all over the place, and it makes it less likely your code will break later. All the code related to outputting a record is in one place, with the struct itself.

Comment: Note that your basic way to serialize is not portable (endianness issues, sizeof issues, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro.

```
out_file.write(((char*)&rec) + offsetof(REC, print_this),
               sizeof(struct REC) - offsetof(REC, print_this));
```

Comment: I think the parentheses are mismatched, but otherwise this is perfect.

Comment: @yinnonsanders, fixed that :)